# iterate on two list of lists

Tags: python, loops

I'm developing a code in ETABS API using python. There is a command for drawing beams. it is like:

```
SapModel.FrameObj.AddByCoord(X1,Y1,Z1,X2,Y2,Z2,"name","section")
```

where X1,Y1,Z1,etc are coordinates in Cartesian coordinate system.
I have two list of lists that each of them are X and Y coordinates. Some thing like:

```
XCoordsList=[[0,5.5,11],[0,6,12.3],[0,7,12.5]]
YCoordsList=[[5,6.1,5.7],[10.5,12.1,12.7],[16,18,19]]
```

These lists are Corresponding, that means X and Y of a certain point is (XCoordList[0,0],YCoords[0,0]);(e.g.:(0,5),(5.5,6.1),(11,5.7))
I want to iterate on these two list and draw my beams.So this is what I have written:

```
Z=3
for m,n in zip(XCoordsList,YCoordsList):
    SapModel.FrameObj.AddByCoord(m[m],n[n],Z,m[m+1],n[n+1],Z,"name","section")
```

and the result is:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list.
What should I do?

Comment: That is because the first item in each is a list: `[0,5.5,11]` (for X) You cannot use the value m to get stuff in a list because m is a list

Comment: @thatrandomperson Yes I get that. but how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is the bad indexing. I have implement a working solution with some comment for better understanding.

My solution is also handling the `X+1` indexing in your formula. You can see in the code my snippet prints the all required parameters.

**Code:**

```
XCoordsList = [[0, 5.5, 11], [0, 6, 12.3], [0, 7, 12.5]]
YCoordsList = [[5, 6.1, 5.7], [10.5, 12.1, 12.7], [16, 18, 19]]
Z = 3

for m, n in zip(XCoordsList, YCoordsList):
    for cont, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(m, n)):  # Iterate on the nested (inside) list pairs
        if cont + 1 in [len(m), len(n)]:  # Test if there is no more item for "cont + 1"
            continue  # If there is not more item, get the nest nested list pair
        print(x, y, Z, m[cont + 1], n[cont + 1], Z, "name", "section")  # Print out the result
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 

0 5 3 5.5 6.1 3 name section
5.5 6.1 3 11 5.7 3 name section
0 10.5 3 6 12.1 3 name section
6 12.1 3 12.3 12.7 3 name section
0 16 3 7 18 3 name section
7 18 3 12.5 19 3 name section
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
XCoordsList=[[0,5.5,11],[0,6,12.3],[0,7,12.5]]
YCoordsList=[[5,6.1,5.7],[10.5,12.1,12.7],[16,18,19]]
Coords = [
    (XCoordsList[array_idx][idx],YCoordsList[array_idx][idx]) 
    for array_idx in range(len(XCoordsList)) 
    for idx in range(len(XCoordsList[array_idx]))
]
print(Coords)
```

You get:

```
[(0, 5), (5.5, 6.1), (11, 5.7), (0, 10.5), (6, 12.1), (12.3, 12.7), (0, 16), (7, 18), (12.5, 19)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to pair them up in a new structure, then use that structure.

```
z = 3
assert len(XCoordsList) == len(YCoordsList)
obj_list = []
for i in range(len(XCoordsList)):
    assert len(XCoordsList[i]) == len(YCoordsList[i])
    obj_list.extend((XCoordsList[i][j], YCoordsList[i][j], z, XCoordsList[i][j+1], YCoordsList[i][j+1], z) for j in range(len(0, XCoordsList[i], 2)))
```

Now, you have a representation you can easily loop over and otherwise manipulate (delete individual points, slice it into smaller parts, etc).

```
for x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 in obj_list:
    SapModel.FrameObj.AddByCoord(
        x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, "name", "section")
```

It's not clear from your question why you have nested lists; if you want to keep that structure, it should be easy to see how to change the code to preserve that.